# The named parameter 'fileExtension' is not defined

Tags: flutter, dart, filepicker

I am using some code from an older version of File Picker, the null safety version will mess up my other code so I'm using 1.1.1.
the code isn't incorrect because it the same on the file picker package example. can anyone help plz?
the code goes as followed

```
void openFileExplorer() async {
try {
  _path = null;
  if (_multiPick) {
    _paths = await FilePicker.getMultiFilePath(
        type: _pickType, **fileExtension**: _extension);
  } else {
    _path = await FilePicker.getFilePath(
        type: _pickType, **fileExtension**: _extension);
  }
  uploadToFirebase();
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  print("Unsupported operation" + e.toString());
}
if (!mounted) return;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: UploadMultipleImageDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class UploadMultipleImageDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  UploadMultipleImageDemo() : super();

  final String title = 'Firebase Storage';

  @override
  UploadMultipleImageDemoState createState() => UploadMultipleImageDemoState();
}

class UploadMultipleImageDemoState extends State<UploadMultipleImageDemo> {
  //
  String _path;
  Map<String, String> _paths;
  List<String> extensions;
  FileType _pickType;
  bool _multiPick = false;
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();
  List<StorageUploadTask> _tasks = <StorageUploadTask>[];

  void openFileExplorer() async {
    try {
      _path = null;
      if (_multiPick) {
        _paths = await FilePicker.getMultiFilePath(
            type: _pickType, allowedExtensions: extensions);
      } else {
        _path = await FilePicker.getFilePath(
            type: _pickType, allowedExtensions: extensions);
      }
      //uploadToFirebase();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Unsupported operation" + e.toString());
    }
    if (!mounted) return;
  }

  // uploadToFirebase() {
  //   if (_multiPick) {
  //     _paths.forEach((fileName, filePath) => {upload(fileName, filePath)});
  //   } else {
  //     if (_path != null) {
  //       String fileName = _path
  //           .split('/')
  //           .last;
  //       String filePath = _path;
  //       upload(fileName, filePath);
  //     }
  //   }
  // }

  // upload(fileName, filePath) {
  //   extensions = fileName.toString().split('.').last as List<String>;
  //   StorageReference storageRef =
  //   FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
  //   final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(
  //     File(filePath),
  //     StorageMetadata(
  //       contentType: '$_pickType/$extensions',
  //     ),
  //   );
  //   setState(() {
  //     _tasks.add(uploadTask);
  //   });
  //   extensions = null;
  // }

  dropDown() {
    return DropdownButton(
      hint: new Text('Select'),
      value: _pickType,
      items: <DropdownMenuItem>[
        new DropdownMenuItem(
          child: new Text('Audio'),
          value: FileType.audio,
        ),
        new DropdownMenuItem(
          child: new Text('Image'),
          value: FileType.image,
        ),
        new DropdownMenuItem(
          child: new Text('Video'),
          value: FileType.video,
        ),
        new DropdownMenuItem(
          child: new Text('Any'),
          value: FileType.any,
        ),
      ],
      onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
        _pickType = value;
      }),
    );
  }

  String _bytesTransferred(StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot) {
    return '${snapshot.bytesTransferred}/${snapshot.totalByteCount}';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> children = <Widget>[];
    _tasks.forEach((StorageUploadTask task) {
      final Widget tile = UploadTaskListTile(
        task: task,
        onDismissed: () => setState(() => _tasks.remove(task)),
        onDownload: () => downloadFile(task.lastSnapshot.ref),
      );
      children.add(tile);
    });

    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: new Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              dropDown(),
              SwitchListTile.adaptive(
                title: Text('Pick multiple files', textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                onChanged: (bool value) => setState(() => _multiPick = value),
                value: _multiPick,
              ),
              OutlineButton(
                onPressed: () => openFileExplorer(),
                child: new Text("Open file picker"),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: ListView(
                  children: children,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> downloadFile(StorageReference ref) async {
    final String url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    final http.Response downloadData = await http.get(url);
    final Directory systemTempDir = Directory.systemTemp;
    final File tempFile = File('${systemTempDir.path}/tmp.jpg');
    if (tempFile.existsSync()) {
      await tempFile.delete();
    }
    await tempFile.create();
    final StorageFileDownloadTask task = ref.writeToFile(tempFile);
    final int byteCount = (await task.future).totalByteCount;
    var bodyBytes = downloadData.bodyBytes;
    final String name = await ref.getName();
    final String path = await ref.getPath();
    print(
      'Success!\nDownloaded $name \nUrl: $url'
          '\npath: $path \nBytes Count :: $byteCount',
    );
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        content: Image.memory(
          bodyBytes,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UploadTaskListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const UploadTaskListTile(
      {Key key, this.task, this.onDismissed, this.onDownload})
      : super(key: key);

  final StorageUploadTask task;
  final VoidCallback onDismissed;
  final VoidCallback onDownload;

  String get status {
    String result;
    if (task.isComplete) {
      if (task.isSuccessful) {
        result = 'Complete';
      } else if (task.isCanceled) {
        result = 'Canceled';
      } else {
        result = 'Failed ERROR: ${task.lastSnapshot.error}';
      }
    } else if (task.isInProgress) {
      result = 'Uploading';
    } else if (task.isPaused) {
      result = 'Paused';
    }
    return result;
  }

  String _bytesTransferred(StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot) {
    return '${snapshot.bytesTransferred}/${snapshot.totalByteCount}';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<StorageTaskEvent>(
      stream: task.events,
      builder: (BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot<StorageTaskEvent> asyncSnapshot) {
        Widget subtitle;
        if (asyncSnapshot.hasData) {
          final StorageTaskEvent event = asyncSnapshot.data;
          final StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot = event.snapshot;
          subtitle = Text('$status: ${_bytesTransferred(snapshot)} bytes sent');
        } else {
          subtitle = const Text('Starting...');
        }
        return Dismissible(
          key: Key(task.hashCode.toString()),
          onDismissed: (_) => onDismissed(),
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text('Upload Task #${task.hashCode}'),
            subtitle: subtitle,
            trailing: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Offstage(
                  offstage: !task.isInProgress,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.pause),
                    onPressed: () => task.pause(),
                  ),
                ),
                Offstage(
                  offstage: !task.isPaused,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.file_upload),
                    onPressed: () => task.resume(),
                  ),
                ),
                Offstage(
                  offstage: task.isComplete,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel),
                    onPressed: () => task.cancel(),
                  ),
                ),
                Offstage(
                  offstage: !(task.isComplete && task.isSuccessful),
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.file_download),
                    onPressed: onDownload,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```